# Search a substring in another string

Tags: c#, substring

```
string name = "BLK000012345summary.pdf";
string fileName = "20150929111111zp2zq23BLK000012345summary.pdf";
```

I have a string `name` which I have to find in `fileName`, if it exists it should return true otherwise false.

Comment: You can use String.Contains

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string name = "BLK000012345summary.pdf";
string fileName = "20150929111111zp2zq23BLK000012345summary.pdf";

bool value = fileName.Contains(name);
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple [`string.Contains`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) will do the job:

```
bool contains = fileName.Contains(name);
```

It will check if the `fileName` contains `name` and will return `true` if so. Note that `Contains` will match case-sensitive. It has to match exactly. If you want to match case insensitive, a regular expression or [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15464440/993547) might be helpful, which tells you to use the current culture to do an `IndexOf`.

Comment: @user3106445 this is the only answer i would even upvote to such a trivial question and the others without any comment / explaination gets accepted. i would accept this answer because SQ should force high quality answers and this one has most of it

Comment: @fubo It doesn't really matter to me, but thanks for your support.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
fileName.Contains(name);
```